# Should I wait to sync the Armory so that I can receive Bitcoins?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, armory

I use Armory. Today I bought some bitcoins but my wallet in that App shows no currency. Instead it said in order to get online you have to install Bitcoin Core. I did that and now it shows "Synchronizing with Network" which is supposed to take a day to download! So, is there any possibility to have my purchased Bitcoin without downloading the blocks?

Comment: @Jestin: I've never used Armory, so I'm not sure that the advice on the linked question is sufficient to solve the issue. Definitely a good explanation of the background of the issue, though.